# How to use a switch...case loop in java inside a nested if...else if...else loop?

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement, nested-loops, break

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.lang.model.util.ElementScanner14;

class mudit {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter!!!");
        final char n = input.next().charAt(0);
        
        art :
        if ((n >= 'a' && n <= 'z' ) || (n >= 'A' && n <= 'z'))
            System.out.println(n + " is an alphabet.");

            dart :
            if ( n == 'a' || n == 'e' || n == 'i' || n == 'o' || n == 'u' || n == 'A' || n == 'E' || n == 'I' || n == 'O' || n == 'U')
                System.out.println("VOWEL");
                break dart;
            else 
                System.out.println("CONSONANT");
                break dart;

        else if ( n * 1 == n)
            System.out.println(n + " is a numerical value.");
        else 
            System.out.println("Something else");

        input.close();
    }
}
```

**When ever i run this code i run into an error.**

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
Syntax error on token "else", delete this token

```
    at mudit.main(mudd.java:28)
```

I want it to tell whether the entered charachter is an alphabet(vowel or consonant) or numerical

*I am using vs code editor.*

Comment: Try enclosing the whole `if` block in brackets `{ }`. Currently `break dart;` isn't in the `if` block. And you should avoid labels and labeled breaks. I haven't seen anyone use those in years now.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decision-making-javaif-else-switch-break-continue-jump/) and focus on getting the syntax (e.g. brackets) right.

Comment: `else if ( n * 1 == n)` is always 'true'. java is strongly typed and the character '1', when fed through 'n*1', is not the digit 1. It's the ascii code of the character '1'. Java isn't javascript :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `if` statement block is more than one line. You can only use an `if` statement, `else` statement, or `else if` statement without curly braces if the block is only a single line. To fix this problem, simply wrap your conditions in curly braces.

On another note, breaking in this context doesn't do anything. You can only break out of a `for-loop`, `advanced for-loop`, `while loop`, `do-while loop`, and `switch` statement. I may have forgotten 1 or 2 scenarios so feel free to remind me!

Comment: _THANKS_ FOR HELPING

Comment: _THANKS_ FOR HELPING

Comment: Why do I feel like this wasn't genuine :p

Answer (score 0):

If there is more then one line inside a "if" or "else" you need to enclose those statements with { }. This should work now.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.lang.model.util.ElementScanner14;

class mudit {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter!!!");
        final char n = input.next().charAt(0);
        
        art :
        if ((n >= 'a' && n <= 'z' ) || (n >= 'A' && n <= 'z')) {
            System.out.println(n + " is an alphabet.");

            dart :
            if ( n == 'a' || n == 'e' || n == 'i' || n == 'o' || n == 'u' || n == 'A' || n == 'E' || n == 'I' || n == 'O' || n == 'U') {
                System.out.println("VOWEL");
                break dart;
            } else { 
                System.out.println("CONSONANT");
                break dart;
            }
        }
        else if ( n * 1 == n)
            System.out.println(n + " is a numerical value.");
        else 
            System.out.println("Something else");

        input.close();
    }
}
```